# Can snk file be copied to other folders?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution that has an .snk file referenced by several projects, also in the same solution.  They reference through AssemblyInfo.cs.  I'm not as familiar with using .snk files.

Can I copy the .snk file to another location, change the AssemblyInfo.cs references and expect everything to be fine?  Or must I generate a new .snk file?

Answer (score 3):

There are two basic policies for .snk files.  The one that a company like Microsoft cares about involves storing the .snk file in a vault that very few people can get to.  To be used only to sign the release assemblies.  Which ensures that nobody can get their hands on that .snk file and use it to sign a malicious substitute assembly.  Copying the .snk file in this case is obviously something they *never* do, that creates just more ways for the .snk file to get into the wrong hands.

The second one is where you just don't care about malicious use of the .snk file and you only use it to give an assembly a strong name so you can put it in the GAC.  It now still doesn't make sense to copy it, that's just busy work without a point.  Just give each project its own .snk file and check it in to source control.

So, no, copying doesn't make sense.  It isn't otherwise something that wouldn't work, the .snk file only stores the private key.